# UITextField / UITextView: I need to be able to detect user "return" key, and I need to be able to do multiline... what can do both?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a multiline UITextfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345561/how-to-create-a-multiline-uitextfield)

UITextField delegate will capture return key: `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`

but it won't do multiline like UITextView can.  But UITextView, can it capture return key?

I need to capture key events: (return) and do multiline: `"\n"....`   What can I do?  thx

Comment: You should split this into two separate questions.

Comment: I need to capture return and do multiline with either UITextField or UITextView.  Neither, from what I see, can do both features... ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A quick google search for "UITextView detect return" came up with this thread:

[UITextView (editing) - detecting that next line event occured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873772/uitextview-editing-detecting-that-next-line-event-occured)

(for convenience sake, I've posted the code below)

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text;
{
    if ( [text isEqualToString:@"\n"] ) {
        //Do whatever you want
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This seems so hacky, wish there was a clean delegate call directly from the `UITextView`